# Trouble Storing pdf in internal storage and viewing it from adobe

Tags: android, android-file

I have created a pdf file in my application and successfully stored that in sdCard, now i want to store the pdf not in my sdcard but in Internal storage as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) but when i open an intent for pdf readers as:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Log.v("Path",file.getAbsolutePath()); // Path data/data/com.cloudchowk.his.patient/files/LIPID PROFILE1300000403.pdf
i.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
startActivity(i);
```

The PDF reader shows an error `The document path is not valid.`

I have tried this on two devices one was rooted and one was not, but it was not working on any of them. What should i do ? any ideas?

Comment: Create a URI and pass the path

Comment: i have already done that, see the code that i have written in the question

Answer (score 0):

Get the path and create URI

```
     File internalFile = getFileStreamPath("pdf path");
     Uri file = Uri.fromFile(internalFile);
     Intent i = new Intent();
     i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     i.setDataAndType(file, "application/pdf");
     startActivity(i);
```

Comment: in the "pdf path" should i write file.getAbsolutePath()? or just the name of file because when i use file.getAbsolutePath() then i get an exception saying 'File path contains a seperator', but now i am using just the filename and i am not getting any exception but just the same error from adobe, 'the document path s not valid'

Comment: pass complete path and check whether file exists

Comment: what you are saying and what i had done are basically the same just using different functions.I have tried your method but the problem still remains, the problem is data stored in internal storage is private to that app only and can never be seen by other app but i want adobe to read this internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

To make a file from internal storage available to other apps the cleanest approach is to use a content provider.
Luckily, Android comes with [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) – an implementation that might just serve your needs.
You don't need to implement code, you just need to specifiy the provider in your manifest.